# Margin between vote/flag buttons and comment text is sometimes too large

Tags: bug, comments, user-interface

For some commments, the margin between the vote/flag buttons and the content of the comment is too large (~64px instead of ~12px).

This must be a fairly new issue (I discovered it today).

I am using Safari 11.0.1 on macOS 10.13.1.

[image: Example of margin with incorrect width]

Comment: note: space resets when you click on add comment link or if there is more than one comment. In other words single comment in a post has space.